# how to refresf the webpage when i press tab in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to click on a tag of other website when i press tab key by using java script
there is a source code of a tag :

```html
<span id="refreshpanel1">
<a class="refresh-avl-enq" onclick="availFareEnq(this,'18191','Sat Nov 15 00:00:00 IST 2014','SL','SMZ','SHG',false)" href="#">Refresh</a>
</span>
```

and my java script code is:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);
function keyDownTextField(e)
{
 
 
   if(e.keyCode==9 || e.which==9)
   {
    
      document.getElementByClassName("refresh-avl-enq").click();

   }
    
   else
      {
         return true;
      }
     
}
```

thanx in advance..!!

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName returns an array. you have missed the s, use id on the a tag instead of class and use the getElementById instead

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName returns an array. you have missed the s, use id on the a tag instead of class and use the getElementById instead. if you have to use a class on the a use

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("refresh-avl-enq")[0].click();
```

presuming the it is the first elem with that classname on the page, make sure to add the s after element

Comment: html code is not mine this code is present on other website and i try to click on it by pressing tab key using javascript so how can i put id on it. is there any good solution

Comment: don't put an id on it then, just use the line of code above and you don't need to touch the code.